# how to install eclipse platform sdk as a new software?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have installed an `Eclipse for RCP and Rap Developers`, below is the installation details:

[Eclipse for RCP and Rap Developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cU6g.png)

What I need is to intall the Eclipse Platform SDK, as shown below:

[Eclipse Platform SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QkNo.png)

But I can't find how to do that, I found how to download a whole Eclipse Platform SDK version, but this is not what I need, what I need is to install it as a plugin inside the Eclipse for RCP and Rap Developers.

Comment: Yes but I can't find it under the available softwares under Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the 'Help > Install New Software...' dialog.

Choose the update site for your Eclipse release (this is different from the main release site). For Eclipse Neon the site is `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6` (change the number at the end to match your release).

The contents of this site should include 'Eclipse Platform SDK' select that and proceed with the install.

Example for Eclipse Neon:
[image: Install New Software]

Comment: Thanks again @greg-449, this is exactly what I need